# Mapping an object of key:value pairs where value is an object

Tags: javascript, object, mapping

**Similar answers found** [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Good day all. I have an object that looks like this:

```
{
ID1: {
  completedThis: true,
  completedThat: false, 
  isArchived: true,
},
ID2: {
  completedThis: true,
  completedThat: false, 
  isArchived: true,
},
}
```

I need to access the data point, "isArchived", from the value of each key(ID..) and then do something with it. I don't want to change the original object while doing this. I really appreciate any and all feedback!

Comment: `Object.values(object).forEach(v => console.log(v.isArchived));`

Comment: what do you want to do with it? what's the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Object.values({
    ID1: {
        completedThis: true,
        completedThat: false,
        isArchived: true,
    },
    ID2: {
        completedThis: true,
        completedThat: false,
        isArchived: true,
    },
}).forEach(value => console.log(value.isArchived))
```

Comment: So simple, thanks @Pierre-Alain EMO!